# ssh Connection refused: how to troubleshoot?

Tags: ssh

I'm trying:

```
$ ssh eric@myserver
```

where `myserver` is a machine in the intranet. I can ping `myserver` or respond to HTTP on port 8080, etc, but when I try `ssh`, I get

```
ssh: connect to host myserver port 22: Connection refused
```

I'm using Ubuntu 10.

`ps -ax`, as suggested gives:

```
eric@Isaiah:~$ ps -ax | grep ssh
Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html
 1641 ?        Ss     0:04 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session
18376 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto ssh
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't have an SSH daemon running. If you look at the output from the `ps ax` command, you see that the only two processes with 'ssh' in the description are `ssh-agent` (which does something entirely different from `sshd`) and the `grep ssh` process that you're using to filter the output of `ps`.

Depending on what distribution installed, you may need to install or run the `ssh` server, usually called `openssh-server` or `sshd` depending on your package manager.

Answer (score 13):

Steps for debugging the above problem:

1. Use `nmap` tool to know which ports are open in that server. `nmap` is a port scanner. Since it may be possible that ssh server is running on a different port.
   `nmap` will give you a list of ports which are open.

   ```
    $ nmap myserver
   ```

2 . Now you can check which server is running on a given port. Suppose in the output of nmap, port 2424 is open. Now you can which server is running on 2424 by using nc(netcat) tool.

```
 $ nc -v -nn myserver portno
```

Suppose the output of 2424 port is:

```
myserver 2424 open
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu5
```

This means ssh is running on 2424.

Keep on changing the portno in the above command and check for all the ports which are listed open by nmap.

Answer (score 3):

That means either the ssh server isn't running on that machine or the firewall isn't allowing ssh through. You can check if ssh is running with 'ps -ax | grep ssh'.

Comment: Edited question to show results of `ps -ax`. Not sure what it means.

Comment: It means `ssh` is not running.

Comment: Weird. I'm not sure why you have twice now offered help that is not really helpful. First you suggest a command useful to check if ssh is running, without telling me how to interpret the results. Then you provide the minimal interpretation of those results, without a hint as to how you arrived at that interpretation, or what action might be appropriate. I'm not sure whether you are trying to help me, and are misjudging my level of experience, or if you are trying to highlight my ignorance.

Comment: The list of processes does not include an `sshd` process, which means `sshd` is not running. The solution is to start `sshd`.

Answer (score 2):

The previous two options are good. You can also use the `-v` or `-vv` arguments.

```
$ ssh -vv eric@myserver
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue too, but in a VirtualBox environment, so to solve it we need to set the IP address to be in the same LAN segment; for example:

On my host machine,
I open `cmd` and type `ipconfig`. I get 100.2.2.1  (for example).

So in the virtual machine we must set the VM's address in `/etc/hosts` to a value like 100.2.2.3, take a look in the final number, and bounce the virtual machine, but before start up the virtual machine configure the network in the settings of the virtual machine, so we need to set the network adapter in bridge connection.

All of this is in a Solaris environment.