# ssh connection refused after reboot

Tags: ssh

I rebooted my Linux Mint 17.3 machine and now when I try to ssh to it, I get "Connection refused" -- what did go wrong? Here are my diagnostic steps:

```
$ ps -ax |grep ssh
 2013 ?     Ss  0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-$
 3346 pts/1 S+  0:00 grep --colour=auto ssh

$nmap MYSERVER
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2019-09-23 15:19 EDT
Nmap scan report for MYSERVER
Host is up (0.00028s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds

$sudo service ssh start
start: Job is already running: ssh

$ sudo service ssh restart
ssh stop/waiting
ssh start/running
```

I got no output to

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh status
```

I read this [ssh Connection refused: how to troubleshoot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21302/ssh-connection-refused-how-to-troubleshoot?newreg=755b132346d948dc9b391ca69b2072c2) but the advice there does not seem to cover my case.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like the service is running, try this to check the status of the service:

```
systemctl status sshd
```

If it is not running you can start it with:

```
systemctl start sshd
```

If you would like the service to start at boot, run:

```
systemctl enable sshd
```

Edit:
 I've just read your question again and realised you've tried running `service ssh start`, I haven't used Linux Mint 17.3, but I'd have thought it's using `systemd` so you'd need to use `systemctl` commands.

You can also run `netstat -tunlp | grep ssh` to see if the service is listening on port 22 as you'd expect. If it shows as listening but you're unable to connect I'd look at the firewall configuration: `iptables -nvL`